# Something dug up my 1yo plumeria, should I prune off its leaves?

Tags: repotting, recovery

I'm growing a very small plumeria in a container (I'm in Wisconsin). It's just a year old - a stem and four leaves. Recently, I put it outside for the summer so it could get proper sun.

Today, I came home to find that something had dug it out of the ground! I'm guessing a squirrel.

I've repotted it and put some mesh over the top of the soil so it's a less attractive dig target. But! It's been liberated from its root system.

I am *guessing* this plant has a chance, since it originally came as a cutting. But! Should I do anything more than put it back in the dirt? Should I prune off its leaves, or at least some of them, to reduce water needs while it tries to grow roots again? Anything else I should consider here?

Thanks!